# Is there a way to call and store data defined in a python script in to julia?

Tags: python, julia

I have a python code which generates a weighted random graph. I want to use the weights generated in that code in a different Julia program. I am able to run the python code through Julia by using PyCall. But I am unable to get any of the data from the graph. Is there any way to do that?

The 'wt' stores the edge data in the python code. 
When I am printing 'wt' in the python code it prints the nodes between which the edge is present and the weights.

This is giving me the required graph. I want to call 'wt' in Julia. How can I do that?

## Python code

```
wt = G.edges.data('weight')
print(wt)
```

## Julia code

```
using PyCall
y = py"exec(open('wtgraph.py').read())"
```

Comment: You can call the python's function from Julia and so use wt directly in Julia.

Answer (score 1):

For your example it would be something like this (you didn't provide the complete code):

```
using PyCall
py"""
import something as G

def py_function(x):
    return G.edges.data('weight')
"""
wt = py"py_function"('weight')
```

Comment: When I am doing this it is giving me the error   
 ERROR: LoadError: syntax: extra token """ after end of expression